# Wireless scanning with HP Envy 5530

Tags: scanner, hplip

I just got an HP Envy 5530. Both printing and scanning work nicely when connected via USB, but when connecting wirelessly I can print but not scan.

```
[1] mike@longshot> hp-probe                                                                                                                                                                                      ~

HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.15.6)
Printer Discovery Utility ver. 4.1

Copyright (c) 2001-15 Hewlett-Packard Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.


--------------------------------
| SELECT CONNECTION (I/O) TYPE |
--------------------------------

  Num       Connection  Description                                               
            Type                                                                  
  --------  ----------  ----------------------------------------------------------
  0*        usb         Universal Serial Bus (USB)                                
  1         net         Network/Ethernet/Wireless (direct connection or JetDirect)
  2         par         Parallel Port (LPT:)                                      

Enter number 0...2 for connection type (q=quit, enter=usb*) ? 1

Using connection type: net


--------------------
| DEVICE DISCOVERY |
--------------------

Probing network for printers. Please wait, this will take approx. 10 seconds...

warning: No devices found on the 'net' bus. If this isn't the result you are expecting,
warning: check your network connections and make sure your internet
warning: firewall software is disabled.

Done.
```

My preferred scanning application is Simple scan, and I have systems running both Arch Linux and Ubuntu that I would like to get this working for.

Is it possible to use Simple scan to scan via wireless with an HP Envy?

Is it possible to do a scan wirelessly at all with an HP Envy?